# Who plays 'Obama' in The End of Time?

Tags: doctor-who, actors, actor-identification

In the 2010 Doctor Who special *The End of Time, Part 1*, the President of the United States makes a minor appearance, as seen in this video:

From his general appearance the actual man (before he turns into just another copy of the Master) is evidently meant to be Barack Obama, presumably the successor to the ill-fated President Winters.

Curiously, this man is not listed on the cast lists for the episodes, either at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Time_(Doctor_Who)), [TARDIS Wikia](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_End_of_Time_(TV_story)), or [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1415016/fullcredits/). Which begs the question: **who played President Obama?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know the actor, he’s a friend's dad! His name is **Roger Haynes**!
This has been an ongoing joke in our friendship group, but now is the time for the truth.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is cool, if true; do you have a photo of Sieur Haynes we can compare?

Comment: The best I can find is the [Susanscottslookalike blog](https://susanscottlookalikes.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/not-a-good-start-to-the-week/barack-obama-roger-haynes/) and (a presumably related) [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/XuaZsgC75aU), and an unsourced credit on [Doctor Who Guide](https://guide.doctorwhonews.net/person.php?code=12357). Although this person certainly bears a close resemblance to the individual in the photo of DistubedNeo's answer, I'm not enough of an expert to declare them the same individual.

Comment: @Xantec - The youtube video is an excellent find. Comparing the two (especially the ear-shape and neckline), they're definitely the same person - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK8oL.png

Answer (score 10):

Simple answer is: Nobody knows.

According to [Barack Obama's TARDIS wiki page](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Barack_Obama), the stand-in is uncredited and we never see his face in the episode. However, the voice is genuinely Barack Obama's, it's archive sound taken from an older speech of his.

Your only hope of figuring it out is the BTS *Doctor Who Confidential* for that episode, called [*Lords and Masters*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Lords_and_Masters_(CON_episode)), in which the actor's face can be seen for a fraction of a second after he finishes shaking his head for that scene:

[image]

Unfortunately, due to the archive sound, any reference to the character's actor is always labelled as Barack Obama, and not the stand-in. So we may never truly know.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure lots of people know.

Comment: Wow Rand al'Thor, nice still. Guess that's him. Pretty decent look-a-like. Tried a reverse google image search and its best guess was "person".

Comment: Ahem. Credit where it's due, please :-)